# If recursive StartDate and EndDate are same, with "Recurrence Pattern as "Daily", then how it can be recurrence appointment?

Tags: calendar, outlook, scheduler, schedule

In OUTLOOK Calendar 2013,

For Example,

Create an appointment with `StartTime="19 03 2014 09 00"` and `EndTime="19 03 2014 09 30"`

Enable Recurrence

```
Recurrence Pattern ="Daily" 
Recur Every="1" Days
```

Range Of Recurrence

`EndBy Mar 19, 2014` (same date)

Therefore the created appointment will be.

> Occurs every Wednesday effective 19-03-2014 until 19-03-2014 from
>   09:00 to 09:30

**The appointment starts and ends in same date then how can we say it as a recursive appointment?**

Thanks
Joy Rex

Comment: It is a recurring appointment with one occurrence. Why it is a problem? Outlook simply does what you tell it to do.

Comment: @Dmitry, If it is one occurrence appointment, then how can we say it as recurrence? how it can be opened in "Single" and as "Series" ?

Comment: Because *you* created it as a recurring appointment? What would be an alternative? Imagine you create an activity, make it recurring with one instance. Save it. Reopen it a second later, the recurrence is gone. "Stupid Outlook! It lost my data again?!"